# R: Calculating a percentage of total by multiple grouping criteria in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe "calls1" and I would like to know how to create a new variable "PercCallsMo" that is the percentage of total calls from the "CallsHandled" variable that each call queue "QUEUE" represents for a given month "MON1_12." My sample data file is below:

```
structure(list(MON1_12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), QUEUE = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("APPLICATION_STATUS", "BENEFITS", "BILLING"
), class = "factor"), CallsHandled = c(9L, 3L, 10L, 27L, 64L, 
17L, 10L, 58L, 8L, 29L, 32L, 12L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L)), .Names = c("MON1_12", "QUEUE", "CallsHandled"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

The result I'm expecting would display the "PercCallsMo" represented by each "QUEUE" on consecutive rows for each month "MON1_12" and should look like this:

```
structure(list(MON1_12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), QUEUE = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("APPLICATION_STATUS", "BENEFITS", "BILLING"
), class = "factor"), CallsHandled = c(9L, 3L, 10L, 27L, 64L, 
17L, 10L, 58L, 8L, 29L, 32L, 12L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), PercCallsMo = c(0.362962963, 0.362962963, 0.362962963, 0.362962963, 
0.554878049, 0.554878049, 0.554878049, 0.488888889, 0.488888889, 
0.37195122, 0.37195122, 0.148148148, 0.148148148, 0.148148148, 
0.073170732, 0.073170732, 0.073170732, 0.073170732, 0.073170732, 
0.073170732)), .Names = c("MON1_12", "QUEUE", "CallsHandled", 
"PercCallsMo"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)

calls1 = calls1 %>%
  group_by(MON1_12) %>%
  mutate(month_total = sum(CallsHandled)) %>%
  group_by(MON1_12, QUEUE) %>%
  mutate(PercCallsMo = sum(CallsHandled)/month_total) %>%
  select(-month_total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R

```
percent <- merge(aggregate(calls1["CallsHandled"],calls1["MON1_12"], sum), 
                 aggregate(calls1["CallsHandled"], calls1[c("MON1_12","QUEUE")], sum),
                 by = "MON1_12")
percent[["PercCallsMo"]] <- percent[["CallsHandled.y"]] / percent[["CallsHandled.x"]]
merge(calls1, percent[c("MON1_12", "QUEUE", "PercCallsMo")])
```

Comment: This produces the percentages but is there a way to do it without altering the size of my dataframe? I need to be able to keep all rows in my dataframe and just have the "PercCallsMo" values repeated for the same month (MON1_12) and QUEUE.

Comment: the final line `merge(calls1, percent[c("MON1_12", "QUEUE", "PercCallsMo")])` should give you all the rows from your original data frame back.  If not, add `all.x = TRUE` to the `merge` call to get all the rows.

Comment: This is strange. The onscreen print out shows the entire dataframe but the file it creates in the environment remains summarized. Any idea why that would occur?

Comment: I don't know how you are saving the data, but the last line just does the merge, it doesn't save it as a variable.  You may need to save the results in a variable.